# What is the right way to save php code in database

Tags: php, database

What is the right way to save (php, html, js and mysql) code in database

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I guess as text....

Comment: So much more information required!

Comment: Is the code to be executed, or just to be shown like on StackOverflow ?

Comment: Are you planning to search this code? If not it doesn't belong in a database.

Comment: Having PHP code in your database that you retrieve and execute is a sure way to get exploited, very easily and very powerfully.  The only reason you'd do something like this is because the PHP isn't code you're running, merely text you are displaying like if you're showing a coding tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't provide any other info:

```
$mycode = '<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>';


mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET mycode = '".mysql_real_escape_string($mycode)."');
```

I seriously doubt you want to do this, though.

Answer (score 3):

D'oh! Are you sure you want to do that? How are you going to version that and work with that code from within an IDE?

However, if you're really inclined to, just keep it in whatever [CLOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_large_object) your DBMS supports.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as I was creating something for the enduser to access and alter some php code.
and simply `include('foo.inc')` the field in a page.  
This is indeed risky and even though it's in a secure area, I wouldn't normaly try, but he who pays the piper calls the tune.

I've been trying for a while and not getting far at all.